# Better way to write this C# Code For List of Lists

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have 3 database tables that hold records that have date properties.  My goal is retrieve all of the dates from each of the 3 tables and put them into a distinct list.  I am currently doing it like this, and it is working:

```
var allYears = new List<List<int>>();
var lstTableOneYears = db.TableOne.Select(x => x.DateTakenRT.Year).Distinct().ToList();
var lstTableTwoYears = db.TableTwo.Select(x => x.DateTakenPIC.Year).Distinct().ToList();
var lstTableThreeYears = db.TableThree.Select(x => x.DateTakenMT.Year).Distinct().ToList();

allYears.Add(lstTableOneYears);
allYears.Add(lstTableTwoYears);
allYears.Add(lstTableThreeYears);

var distinctYears = allYears.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
```

The above is working, but I was hoping there was a better way to write this using less lines?  Maybe better usage of LINQ?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var distinctYears = db.TableOne.Select(x => x.DateTakenRT.Year)
    .Union(db.TableTwo.Select(x => x.DateTakenPIC.Year))
    .Union(db.TableThree.Select(x => x.DateTakenMT.Year))
    .ToList();
```

---

*On a side note you could have used `AddRange` instead of having a List that contains Lists in your code above.*

Comment: Awesome! I haven't used `Union` before.  Very cool!  Thank you!  Yes you're right.. I could've used `AddRange` for sure.. I have used that before haha surprised I didn't think to use it.  Thanks again!